# Sublime Text 2 and HTML5 Boilerplate build script

Tags: build-script, html5boilerplate, sublimetext

After falling in love with Sublime Text I'm now getting ready to leave Aptana. ST2 seems to have a built in build function. If i go to "Tools"->"Build System"->"New Build System" i can define my own build commands but can i some how tell ST2 to use the build script from HTML5 Boilerplate? So that when i press F7 or ctrl+B it builds from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...
```

It will open a new custom build file you can customize. Then you just have to save it with your desired name, restart Sublime and it will appear in the list along with the others.

[Here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) you can find the customization options and instructions.

To run boilerplate you have to specify the right path to Boilerplate runbuildscript.bat, by default it's inside the build folder.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer earlier. I didn't have the time to try it out at the time :/